# Very large odds ratio- binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have obtained a very large odds ratio and standard error for my interaction term after running a binary logistic regression. My study has 4 conditions and 3 dependant variables, however, 1 of the dependent variables is a categorical and so I was told by my supervisor to conduct a binary regression for that dv separately while conducting a Manova for the other variables. The do is a simple yes or no answer to signing up so a fictional follow up study. I have 52 participants. Overall, 44 participants responded yes and 8 responded no. I am aware that the odds ratio may have been so large because I have a very small number in some of my cells. How would I reports very large odds ratio according to apa guidelines or should I run different analysis? The odds ratio is 6 figures so it is huge! Any help would be appreciated. This is for my undergraduate dissertation.

Comment: "Very large" is quite possibly your software's approximation to "infinite" - see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45803).

Comment: Unfortunately, only having 8 subjects with a "no" response limits you to a descriptive analysis (frequencies and percentages). Binary logistic regression often requires at least 10 subjects per predictor variable in the smallest response group. This [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26016/sample-size-for-logistic-regression) will likely be a helpful read for you.