# Power calculation: What does it mean if the observed effect size is lesser than the expected effect size in power calculation?

Tags: statistical-power, genetics

I am conducting a regression analysis on TNF-a in relation to a genetic marker. I performed a post-hoc power calculation using a software called Quanto. The mean(SD) of my outcome variable is 34(14). The Minor Allele Frequency of the genetic marker is 0.102. The Beta coefficient of the predictor from the regression model is 2.852 and my sample size is 799

The power calculation result shows that the minimum detectable effect size (Beta) for a sample size of 781 is 3.271, while the observed effect size (Beta) from the regression model is 2.852. What can I conclude from these results? If the observed effect size is lower than the expected effect size, does it mean that the study is underpowered?

Comment: You can conclude no more than what is presented from the regression. Postbox power has been discussed extensively here and elsewhere, and the conclusion is your energy is best spent elsewhere.

Comment: I am not very experienced in stat. If you can help me with a reference, will be great

Comment: Since you are modeling the outcome as random, why would you be at all surprised or concerned to observe an outcome that varies a little bit below or above what you expected?  Nature doesn't suspend the laws of probability just because you were foresighted enough to do a power analysis beforehand!

Comment: @arshad see this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384011/power-analysis-for-logistic-regression-with-dummy-independent-variables/384013#384013

Comment: Consider that a sample mean with a different value from a hypothesized population mean doesn't necessarily imply that the hypothesized mean was wrong (it may be due to sampling variation). So it is here - except your calculation using a prior effect size doesn't need to have been an *accurate* description of the actual situation  -- if the power calculation was about finding the sample size to attain a particular power *if that was the effect size*, this property may be desirable whether or not that was really the effect size.