# How to do low scale logistic regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, statistical-significance

Let's I have data on 10 customers. For example, I have their Age, gender, income, marital status and whether they bought a car or not.

Now I have another new customer data. How can I predict/find out whether this new customer will buy a car or not?

Is there any logistic regression for low sample data?

Is there any simple statistical approach that can guide us to know whether the new customer will buy a car or not?

Or it simply cannot be done (effectively) because of low data?

I understand with low data, we cannot make any reliable predictions but don't organizations in real time face this challenge?

Do they use any simple statistical technique like t test, chi squared test, hypothesis test etc to at least gain some insight on whether he will buy a car or not?

Comment: 10 obs is considered to little for logistic regression  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26016/sample-size-for-logistic-regression

Comment: How about the same for time series? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/523294/how-to-do-low-scale-time-series-prediction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who tries to make predictions from limited data needs at least to be wary of overfitting: finding a "result" that happens to fit a small data set well but that fails miserably when you try to apply the "result" to a new sample. There's a particular problem with logistic regression, where it can be surprisingly easy to get "[perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500)": a combination of predictors that exactly predicts outcomes *in your limited data set*. There's no assurance that "perfect" result will apply to a new case.

Chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) is a useful reference on how to do modeling with multiple predictors, with the case-number/overfitting issue covered in Section 4.4. A rough rule of thumb for logistic regression is that you should only evaluate one predictor per 15 of the *lowest-prevalence* outcomes. The [link provided by kjetil b halvorsen](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26016/28500) goes into more detail.

One way to try to work around limited data is to use a penalization technique that counteracts overfitting. [Ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ridge-regression/info) is one useful approach, as it keeps all of your predictors in the model while reducing the magnitudes of their coefficients to avoid overfitting. But if you only have 10 customers you have no more than 5 in the lower-prevalence outcome category, and your optimal ridge-regression model probably wouldn't be much different from a null model.

Comment: thanks, upvoted and accepted