# The rule of 10 events for logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I want to assess whether the rule of 10 events is in my logistic regression model. My sample is small and I have overfitted my model which goes against the rule.
However, I would like to present this graphically plotting the number of events per variable versus the estimate (OR)

How can I come up with this plot?

Comment: The rule is just a rule of thumb, there is no guarantees whatsoever that 10:1 would be enough ratio. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26016/35989