# Can I use logistic regression if one category of the dependent variable has a very low frequency?

Tags: regression, logistic, frequency, dependent-variable

An example of 100 subjects. Let's say I wish to study the impact of literacy levels (0 as limited and 1 as adequate), anxiety levels (0 as no anxiety and 1 as severe anxiety) and sex (0 for female and 1 for male) on the decision that has been made.

We have decision A and decision B.

the frequency of decision A is 98 and the frequency of decision B is 2.

In such as scenario, is it reasonable to use logistic regression where the dependent variable is the binary variable (decision) ? Why/why not ?

Comment: Near-duplicate [Does an unbalanced sample matter when doing logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression). In your case you also have a small sample size, N=100.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A rule of thumb is to have $10$-$15$ members of the minority class per feature included in your regression.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/162150/247274) In your case, you have two such members, meaning that even one feature is too many to include.

[Imbalance isn't really a problem, but a low number of minority-class observations might be.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) This is to say that $98000$ and $2000$ might not be so problematic but $98$ and $2$ probably is.

Unless you get more data, I do not see much hope for saying anything other than there being a $2\%$ chance of decision $\text{B}$, perhaps with a confidence interval.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you so much so illuminating

Comment: (+1) Also one might look up logistic regression in connection with the terms 'narrow distribution' or 'rare events' as there is a literature covering specialized techniques for these situations.

Comment: It is helpful to consider answering the question in the case where there is no X variable, and consider the resulting uncertainty in the estimate. Then realize that the problem is worse when you introduce X variables.

Comment: *"Unless you get more data"*... they can also do synthetic data generation; but to do that they'd need an a-priori assumption/knowledge of the distribution of response variable as a fn of {literacy, anxiety, sex}.