# How to increase McFadden score and choose proper predictor for binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

This is my first modelling indeed so I need your kind help!

- **Model goal:** Generating a predicted surface for forest-loss
- **Model input variables:** Response variable is just coded 1(loss) or 0(not loss) and explanatory variables are several types of distance
  like distance from several types of roads, distance from nearest
  markets,distance from forest guard posts.

I ran the model and found as below:

```
summary(logit_binom_mdl_1)

Call:
glm(formula = expression_logit_binom_mdl_1, family = binomial(logit), 
    data = model_data)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-2.3371576  -0.9578162   0.1747445   0.9299094   3.3762210  

Coefficients:
                                     Estimate       Std. Error   z value               Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  -2.6372122561920  0.0826167037310 -31.92105 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Beat_office_dst               0.0000572366865  0.0000021478441  26.64844 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
BF_Oct_201_dst               -0.0000695402804  0.0000036434505 -19.08638 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Blocks_line_dst               0.0000310596318  0.0000196856470   1.57778              0.1146160    
elevation_hig_dst            -0.0014374765468  0.0000447480650 -32.12377 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
elevation_lo_dst              0.0006067207693  0.0001493724256   4.06180     0.0000486959963114 ***
elevation_mi_dst             -0.0023395617764  0.0002508881030  -9.32512 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
GLG_av_dst                   -0.0000021850018  0.0000015278637  -1.43010              0.1526876    
GLG_cs_dst                    0.0000174879417  0.0000014577921  11.99618 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
GLG_QTd_dst                   0.0000100487083  0.0000017663662   5.68892     0.0000000127848583 ***
GLG_QT_dst                    0.0000008388661  0.0000020377568   0.41166              0.6805875    
GLG_Tb_dst                   -0.0000190831936  0.0000019375752  -9.84901 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
GLG_T_dst                     0.0000281789998  0.0000009009786  31.27599 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
GrowthCenter_dst              0.0000532466372  0.0000034933025  15.24249 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
MH_Agri_Fem_dst               0.0000110347697  0.0000009850395  11.20236 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
MH_H5__dst                   -0.0001765046853  0.0000125257541 -14.09134 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
MH_HT_OWNE_dst               -0.0000489452953  0.0000168002080  -2.91337              0.0035755 ** 
MH_STRUCTURE_KUTCH_dst       -0.0001799507048  0.0000134315966 -13.39757 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_Agri_Fem_dst              -0.0000105223873  0.0000149567743  -0.70352              0.4817319    
ML_ELECTRICITY_CONNECTIO_dst -0.0003124420961  0.0000158480192 -19.71490 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_Empled__dst                0.0003859945406  0.0000174389931  22.13399 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_FEMALE_POP_Densit_dst      0.0007772630503  0.0001556120054   4.99488     0.0000005887283899 ***
ML_H20_2_dst                  0.0004227684414  0.0000188553775  22.42164 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_H30_4_dst                 -0.0001141312330  0.0000063862057 -17.87152 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_H50_5_dst                  0.0000060236982  0.0000131305196   0.45876              0.6464097    
ML_H60_6_dst                  0.0001409434497  0.0000103289876  13.64543 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_H6_dst                     0.0000039355103  0.0000150370433   0.26172              0.7935365    
ML_HH__dst                    0.0000265847491  0.0000089248124   2.97875              0.0028943 ** 
ML_HT_RENTE_dst               0.0002917755067  0.0000320514785   9.10334 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_HT_RENT_FRE_dst           -0.0001032600886  0.0000150746489  -6.84992     0.0000000000073893 ***
ML_Indstry__dst              -0.0016095069561  0.0001320407437 -12.18947 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LITERACY_RATE_BOT_dst      0.0008032339921  0.0000748917611  10.72527 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LITERACY_RATE_FEMAL_dst   -0.0003196295180  0.0000295847669 -10.80385 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LITERACY_RATE_MAL_dst     -0.0007005611023  0.0000658538091 -10.63813 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LITERATE_BOTH_YE_dst      -0.0009855379265  0.0000601450709 -16.38601 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LITERATE_FEMALE_YE_dst     0.0000541721486  0.0000225971169   2.39730              0.0165162 *  
ML_LITERATE_MALE_YE_dst       0.0006889369874  0.0000596517421  11.54932 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_LknJB__dst                 0.0002105347950  0.0000174903284  12.03721 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_Service__dst              -0.0003691609855  0.0000279304762 -13.21714 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_STRUCTURE_JHUPR_dst       -0.0000555295006  0.0000048941290 -11.34615 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_STRUCTURE_PUCK_dst         0.0008255026207  0.0000866943661   9.52199 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
ML_STRUCTURE_SEMI_PUCK_dst   -0.0000073656704  0.0000340292187  -0.21645              0.8286359    
MM_AVG_SIZE_H_dst            -0.0000762127880  0.0000043423667 -17.55098 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
MM_H10_1_dst                  0.0002392837774  0.0000111204724  21.51741 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
MM_H15_1_dst                  0.0000040731167  0.0000076379295   0.53327              0.5938432    
MM_H25_2_dst                  0.0002181484888  0.0000174570798  12.49628 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Pourashava_cityCor_dst        0.0000689663031  0.0000015116355  45.62363 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Roads_nationa_dst            -0.0000220468464  0.0000026340514  -8.36994 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Roads_regional_feede_dst     -0.0000294362636  0.0000034028745  -8.65041 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Roads_regiona_dst             0.0000650685545  0.0000040394690  16.10820 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Settlements_CH_dst           -0.0002731157854  0.0000092993602 -29.36931 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
slope_hig_dst                -0.0010063634964  0.0000970452353 -10.37005 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
slope_lo_dst                 -0.0037709649780  0.0003477800580 -10.84296 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
slope_mi_dst                 -0.0029802985240  0.0002645044963 -11.26748 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Small_Hat_Bazar_dst           0.0000435426146  0.0000037357201  11.65575 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Upazilla_lin_dst              0.0001358771062  0.0000050153571  27.09221 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
Zilla_lin_dst                 0.0000191196986  0.0000028947347   6.60499     0.0000000000397539 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 258078.10  on 186163  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 211434.55  on 186107  degrees of freedom
AIC: 211548.55

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5


> PseudoR2(logit_binom_mdl_1)
         McFadden      Adj.McFadden         Cox.Snell        Nagelkerke  McKelvey.Zavoina            Effron             Count         Adj.Count 
     0.1807342677      0.1802847914      0.2216281372      0.2955041829      0.3173878971      0.2233253378      0.6916159945      0.3832319890 
              AIC     Corrected.AIC 
211548.5463978653 211548.5819260052
```

And the ROC curve (AUC is 0.7718432397)

[image: ROC]

**Now my question is how can I improve McFadden (>.2). I am trying for this for many days went though several articles.**

PS. For further background on this question please refer at [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232488/how-to-explain-the-spatial-relation-of-forest-loss-hotspots-with-several-others/232491).

Answer (score 1):

Besides McFadden statistic (with which I am not familiar), there are some general advises I want to provide you with.

**1**) I understand that you have a huge sample size. While in theory this is not a problem (and sometime it is indeed desirable), it could have a downside tough: it could make very small differences (in the values of your predictors) statistically significant just as a result of a huge sample size

**2**) You should be sure to use a number of predictors that is not disproportionately large relative to the sample size.

**3**) Since you are dealing with spatial data, you may experience spatial autocorrelation among the **model residuals**. That can be easily checked for extracting your point locations' coordinates (along with your model residuals) and calculating a measure of spatial autocorrelation with any spatial analysis program (I found SAM program very handy: https://www.ecoevol.ufg.br/sam/). If you have spatial autocorrelation, one of the approaches used in literature is to subsample from your universe of points in order to increase the interpoint distance reltive to the whole dataset. This could alleviate spatial autocorrelation. This would also allow you to deal with a smaller sample size (complying with issue **1** above), but you will always need to check if the new sample size is fit to the number of predictors (see issue **2** above).

Comment: I did not get your point 2. I have almost 60 predictors for ~200000 loss points and ~200000 non loss points. Thank you for you effort! I need to increase model performance. All predictors are distance based. Mcfaden score of .2 to.4 is for good model fit. I found this in some journal. Infact i am thinking of auto correlation check just to increase quality these type of criterion.

Comment: Let's put it this way: your sample size sounds way too huge to me. Try to subsample in order to get a sample size which is both smaller AND still fit to the number of predictors. As for the latter, a rule of thumb for a minimum sample size is: N=10xK/p, where k is the number of predictors, p is the proportion of negative or positive casse, whichever is smaller.

Comment: I am sorry for messing up. I have~ 93000 loss and ~93000 non loss points. Could  you please clarify the formula for me . I see N will be 10*60/93000=10 is it right? So i need 10 representative points?

Comment: assume you have 1000 positive cases and 1000 negative cases, your p would be 0.5 (that is, 1000/2000). The minimum number of predictors would be: 10*60/0.5. Modify the above accordingly, on the basis of your actual number of positive and negative cases.

Comment: And do not overlook the huge sample size issue.

Comment: thank you any reference for `N=10xK/p`. Is there any way to find the points that has least autocorrelation from the whole ~ 93000 points

Comment: Really and truly, I do not know. What I happen to do was (A) to set sampling points with a minimum spacing of (say) 20 m at the very initial stage of my study; (B) to subsample from that sample, eventually arriving at a sample size of circa 7000 points in total. The rationale beyond subsampling was to further increase the inter-point distance. On top of that, following one of the references I provided on GisStatExchange, I added as extra-predictors the points' coordinates. That said, there is still something I wanted to stress.

Comment: What I wanted to stress is that you seem to have a very large number of predictors. Are all those relevant to your analysis, i.e. you are including those in your model on the basis of literature in your field, or are you simply trying to throw all of them into the model and seeing what happen?

Comment: Thank you for your kind effort! now I have thought that I need to divide whole points(loss and non-loss) into several grids and afterwards I will take a random sample from each of these grids, I think this would lessen the effect of spatial autocorrelation. Now can you help me with how can I choose what will be the optimum dimension of the grid that i need.